# Is there a Swipe tool for ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, swipe

I was researching the ESRI JavaScript API, and was wondering if there is a sample which shows layer swiping in the browser.

Is there such a Swipe sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could find two such samples.

1. There is a sample from ESRI which uses ArcGIS Online. [swipe-map-storytelling-template-js](https://github.com/Esri/swipe-map-storytelling-template-js)
2. There is an sample on ArcScripts [here](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16786) by Sathya Prasad

Comment: thanks for sharing..Its really nice example (like to show changes or comparison)

Comment: Regarding http://storymaps.esri.com/templates/swipe/ this application can I create similar application ( only back-ground layer will be different ) and we don't have account on ArcGIS Online

Comment: @Sunil I haven't understood your question. Are you asking whether you can use the first sample with your own Services? Out of the box I don't think so, but you could get ideas from it, and use that in your own application.

Comment: @ Devdatta Tengshe                                          :Are you asking whether you can use the first sample with your own Services? : Yes but I check the code and found that they have inserted ArcGIS Online web map id for that.. ..and we don't have ArcGIS Online subscription  ..